# Java Servlet Redirection

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, servlets

Hello I am trying to make an online tv show tracker the front end is implemented just like this http://tiii.me/[1](http://tiii.me/)

You enter a show name and the background image changes and the small picture appears downwards just like the website given above, please refer to that.

The problem i am facing is that i have a servlet called which is called once the button is pressed, hence redirecting from the page and all the computations done on the html page are gone once i redirect back from the servlet.

Here is the html for my search

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet'    type='text/css'>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<style>
        body{
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }

    #custom-search-input {
            margin:0;
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #custom-search-input .search-query {
            padding-right: 3px;
            padding-right: 4px \9;
            padding-left: 3px;
            padding-left: 4px \9;
            /* IE7-8 doesn't have border-radius, so don't indent the padding */

            margin-bottom: 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        #custom-search-input button {
            border: 0;
            background: none;
            /** belows styles are working good */
            padding: 2px 5px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            position: relative;
            left: -28px;
            /* IE7-8 doesn't have border-radius, so don't indent the padding */
            margin-bottom: 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            color:#D9230F;
        }

        .search-query:focus + button {
            z-index: 3;   
        }

        .bg 
        {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url(images/126.42.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: 50% 0;
            -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
            -moz-filter: blur(3px);
            filter: blur(3px);
            filter: alpha(Opacity=10);
            opacity: .6;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s;
            -moz-transition: all .3s;
            -o-transition: all .3s;
            transition: all .3s;
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        }

</style>

<script>

var val;

function myFunction() 
{
    val = document.getElementById("tvshow").value;

    var i=0;
    var data = {results: []};
    var imurl;

    $.ajax ({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://api.trakt.tv/search/shows.json/58269f85e4333c18234bb68b93397031/'+ val +'/5/seasons/',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            json: "callbackname",
            crossDomain : true,
            success: function (result) {
              $.each(result, function (i, show) {

                // write everything in an array
                data.results.push({id: this.tvdb_id, text: this.title, runtime: this.runtime, poster: this.images.poster, bg: this.images.fanart});
                console.log(this.title);

                //selectedTVshow = this.title;
                // results = data.results;

                // return array

                if(i==0) 
                {
                    imurl=this.images.fanart;
                    i++;
                }
                $('.bg').css('background-image','url('+ imurl +')');

                //imurl=this.images.fanart;
              })
            },
            error: function (data) {
              console.log('error');
            }
          })

}

</script>


<title>T.V Dose</title>
```

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <span class="bg"></span>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/TVDose/addshow" method="POST" class="form form-signup" role="form">                 
            <span class="input-group-btn" style="float:right;">
                <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="myFunction()" type="submit">
                    <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="font-size: 2.0em"></span>
                </button>
            </span>

            <div id="custom-search-input" style="margin-top: 30%">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" id="tvshow" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Type in a show" name="show"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Following is the Servlet Post Method That is being used the annotations are correctly used

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
        {

    HttpSession newSession=request.getSession(false);
    if(newSession==null)
    {
        //response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Jotter2/");
    }
    else
    {

            String showname = request.getParameter("show");
            Document sid = Jsoup.connect("http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/search.php?show="+showname+"&exact=1").timeout(1000*100).get();
            Elements show_id=sid.select("showid");
            String shwname=show_id.first().text();
            System.out.print(shwname);
            //System.out.print(sid);

            String sname=sid.select("name").first().text();
            Shows temp= new Shows();
            int id=Integer.parseInt(shwname);
            temp.setShow_id(id);
            temp.setTitle(sname);
            Login usr = (Login)newSession.getAttribute("user");
            temp.setPid(usr.getPid());
            DataAccessUtil.save(temp);

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid="+id+"").get();
            System.out.print(doc);
            Elements ep_name=doc.select("title");
            Elements air_date=doc.select("airdate");
            int count=ep_name.size();
            Episodes[] ep_temp=new Episodes[count];
            int i=0;

            while(i<count)
            {
                ep_temp[i]=new Episodes();
                i++;
            }
            int a=0;

            String date_air;
            SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            while(a<count)
            {
                ep_temp[a].setEp_name(ep_name.get(a).text());
                ep_temp[a].setPid(usr.getPid());
                ep_temp[a].setS_id(temp.getSid());
                date_air=air_date.get(a).text();
                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = dt1.parse(date_air);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
                ep_temp[a].setAir_date(sqlDate);
                DataAccessUtil.save(ep_temp[a]);
                a++;

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ajax, so it should not be refreshed on `<form/>` submit. You should return false at the end of `myFunction()`

```
function myFunction() {

     .................
  return false;
}
```